# How to restore Class instance variable having only its method variable

Tags: python

`MyClass` has two methods defined: `methodA` and `methodB`.

After declaring `foo` instance of `MyClass` I proceed with declaring a variable `first_method_a` which is `foo` object's `methodA`.

```
foo = MyClass()
first_method_a = foo.methodA
```

Next, I go ahead an loose `foo` variable left myself only with variable `first_method_a` which still points to `foo.methodA` and it is functional.

```
foo = None
first_method_a()
```

Which prints:

```
this is method A
```

Now, how can I run `methodB` only having `first_method_a` variable?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()

    def methodA(self):
        print 'this is method A'

    def methodB(self):
        print 'this is method B'


foo = MyClass()
first_method_a = foo.methodA

foo = None

first_method_a()
```

Comment: Super is just a result of Sublime using Class declaration template snippet.